# Keyboard control in UAC Window

Tags: windows, uac, touch-typing

Can i control the UAC window from keyboard ('y' or 'n'). I noticed an underscore for both Y and N, but pressing the keys doesn't change anything.

[image: UAC Window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands with underscored letters are typically invoked by pressing that letter while holding left <kbd>Alt</kbd>. So:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for *Yes*
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for *No*.